# PHP generator return type

Tags: php, iterator, generator, iterable, php-generators

I've never used generators in PHP before and there are no examples in the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php) that show the return type declaration.

In PhpStorm, there is an error in the IDE when I do this:

```
public function getDataIncrementally(): void {
    yield from [/* some large set of numbers*/];
}
```

The error is:

> Generators may only declare a return type of Generator, Iterator or Traversable, or iterable, void is not permitted.

I can see the inheritance tree is `Traversable` -> `Iterator` -> `Generator`. Meanwhile, [`iterable`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php) is a new pseudo-type introduced in PHP 7.1.

Would it be appropriate to use `iterable` for the return type declaration if I only need to support PHP >= 7.1?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your return type is `Generator`, but you are using `void`. Try the following:

```
public function getDataIncrementally(): \Generator {
    yield from [/* some large set of numbers*/];
}
```

Comment: Is `Generator` recommended over `iterable`? That's the question I'm really hoping to get an answer for

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 no, `Generator` is more accurate data type, `iterable` is more wide, because you can use also `Iterator`,  `Generator`, `Traversable` as return type

Comment: If you would like that your interface would support `Array`, `Iterator`, and `Generator` at the same time you should use `iterable`. It is would be preferable for `Interface`.